# How do you use Bottle within a Python class with methods instead of functions?

Tags: python, class, bottle

I'm working on a project in which an API which I'm creating with Bottle needs to be integrated into a class. I'm not sure how to integrate its functionality into class methods. This doesn't work:

```
class Rest_API:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def generic_function(self, input):
        return("Generic Function Result: {}".format(input))

my_api = Rest_API()

#DOESN'T WORK
bottle.get("/generic_url")(my_api.generic_function(input))

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The error is as follows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Generic Function Result'
```

This version below does run, but it doesn't meet my needs because the function needs to take input.

```
class Rest_API:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def generic_function(self):
        return("Generic Function Result")

my_api = Rest_API()

bottle.get("/generic_url")(my_api.generic_function)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the value of the input variable in `bottle.get("/generic_url")(my_api.generic_function(input))` ?

Comment: What is "input"? Where does it come from?